# SQL not retrieving/displaying data needed

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

So I am retrieving data through SQL and its for a statement page. It has the clients, date, transaction, debit, credit and balance columns. Now when it comes to a transaction that is a credit and not a debit, it does not show.

E.G - http://oi57.tinypic.com/16m1yeq.jpg

Check image above and you will see credits are not showing. 
If there is an issue as to why it isn't displaying, please help me! I know there is something in the code to fix around the "nDrTotal" & nCrTotal

Thanks!
The question is... Why is the negative amount not showing in the debit table?
Here is my code for where it is getting the data -

```vb
Function ApplyStatementDetails(ByVal sContent As String, ByVal sClientID As String, ByVal sDate As String, ByVal sSection As String) As String
    Dim sSQL As String, sOut As String, rsStatement As SqlDataReader, sHTML As String = "", iLines As Integer, iCount As Integer
    Dim nInvTotal As Double, n90Days As Double = 0, n60Days As Double = 0, n30Days As Double = 0, nCurrent As Double = 0, dCompareDate As Date
    Dim nBalance As Double = 0

    sOut = ApplyCompanyDetails(sContent)

    'response.write sSQl: response.end
    rsStatement = New SqlCommand(sSQL, cnStatemnt).ExecuteReader

    Dim bFirst As Boolean = True, sClient As String = "", sAddress As String = ""
    Dim nDRTotal As Double = 0, nCRTotal As Double = 0, nPaymentsAlloc As Double = 0
    Do While rsStatement.Read
        If bFirst Then
            iCount = 0
            sClient = EmptyIfNull(rsStatement("Company"))
            If sClient = "" Then sClient = EmptyIfNull(rsStatement("Salutation"))
            sAddress = DesignAddress(rsStatement("Address1"), rsStatement("Address2"), rsStatement("Address3"), rsStatement("Address4"), rsStatement("Postcode"))
            sOut = Replace(sOut, "$$Client_ID$$", sClientID)
            sOut = Replace(sOut, "$$Client_Name$$", nbspIfEmpty(sClient))
            sOut = Replace(sOut, "$$Client_Address$$", sAddress)
            If Request.QueryString("date") <> "" Then
                sOut = Replace(sOut, "$$Statement_Date$$", Request.QueryString("date"))
            Else
                sOut = Replace(sOut, "$$Statement_Date$$", sDate)
            End If
            bFirst = False
        End If
        nDRTotal = Math.Round(ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("InvoicesPH")) + ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("InvoicesContract")) + ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("InvoicesFE")) + ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("InvoicesCMP")), 2)
        If nDRTotal = 0 Then
            nCRTotal = ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("Payments"))
            nPaymentsAlloc = -ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("CreditsAlloc"))
            nInvTotal = Math.Round(-nPaymentsAlloc - nCRTotal, 2)
        Else
            nCRTotal = -ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("Payments")) + ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("Adjustments")) + ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("Credits")) - ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("CreditsAlloc"))
            nPaymentsAlloc = 0
            Select Case rsStatement("Type")
                Case "TR", "CH", "CA", "CC"
                    nPaymentsAlloc = GetPaymentsAlloc(rsStatement("InvoiceNo"))
            End Select
            nInvTotal = Math.Round(ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("InvoicesPH")) + ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("InvoicesContract")) + ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("InvoicesFE")) + ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("InvoicesCMP")) - ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("Payments")) + ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("Adjustments")) + ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("Credits")) - ZeroIfNull(rsStatement("CreditsAlloc")) + nPaymentsAlloc, 2)
        End If
        '               
        If nInvTotal <> 0 Then
            iLines = iLines + 10
            sHTML = sHTML & "<tr><td class=""data"" align=""center"">" & FormatDate(rsStatement("InvoiceDate"), sDateFormat) & "</td>" & _
             "<td class=""data"">" & FormatRef(rsStatement("Type"), rsStatement("InvoiceNo")) & "</td>" & _
             "<td class=""data"" align=""right"">" & ShowValue(nDRTotal, rsStatement("Type"), "DR") & "</td>" & _
             "<td class=""data"" align=""right"">" & ShowValue(nCRTotal, "CR", "CR") & "</td>" & _
             "<td class=""data"" align=""right"">" & ShowValue(nInvTotal, rsStatement("Type"), "TOTAL") & "</td></tr>"
            '"<td class=""data"" align=""right"">" & ShowValue(nDRTotal + nCRTotal + nPaymentsAlloc, rsStatement("Type"), "TOTAL") & "</td></tr>"               

            dCompareDate = rsStatement("InvoiceDate")

            ' 12/11/13 changed statement ageing to days base for statements dated mid-month  MB
            If DateDiff("d", dCompareDate, CDate(sDate)) >= 90 Then
                n90Days = n90Days + nInvTotal
            ElseIf DateDiff("d", dCompareDate, CDate(sDate)) >= 60 Then
                n60Days = n60Days + nInvTotal
            ElseIf DateDiff("d", dCompareDate, CDate(sDate)) >= 30 Then
                n30Days = n30Days + nInvTotal
            Else
                nCurrent = nCurrent + nInvTotal
            End If
        End If
    Loop

    sOut = Replace(sOut, "$$Statement_Data$$", sHTML)
    sOut = Replace(sOut, "$$90Days_Amount$$", ShowBalance(n90Days))
    sOut = Replace(sOut, "$$60Days_Amount$$", ShowBalance(n60Days))
    sOut = Replace(sOut, "$$30Days_Amount$$", ShowBalance(n30Days))
    sOut = Replace(sOut, "$$Current_Amount$$", ShowBalance(nCurrent))
    sOut = Replace(sOut, "$$Total_Amount$$", ShowBalance(n90Days + n60Days + n30Days + nCurrent))
    rsStatement.Close() : rsStatement = Nothing

    If sSection <> "" Then
        ApplyStatementDetails = GetDocumentSection(sOut, "all") & GetDocumentSection(sOut, sSection)
    Else
        ApplyStatementDetails = sOut
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Please format the question. Also why don't you use SPs rather than inline sql

Comment: @Seminda i included the question above

Comment: Some security vulnerabilities here such as trusting user input: `Out = Replace(sOut, "$$Statement_Date$$", Request.QueryString("date"))`

Answer (score 0):

This code looks more like vbscript than VB.Net. VB.Net is very different, and a lot of the conventions learned from vbscript no longer make sense when using VB.Net.

Reading the method, I see this at the top:

```
Dim sSQL As String
```

Followed soon after by this:

```
rsStatement = New SqlCommand(sSQL, cnStatemnt).ExecuteReader
```

But nowhere in between is a value ever assigned to `sSQL`. It's executing an empty SQL string.

Comment: I removed the SQL statement from the post as it is long and I don't believe it has anything to do with the SQL statement. I define the SQL fine, its just when an account's credit is negative, it doesn't display on the table